# Failing to compile my Biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

As I wrote in the title, I'm trying without success to compile the bibliography of my thesis. I'm using the package Biblatex.
I know that there are other questions about the same topic, but I couldn't fix my problem.

Here are the packages I'm using.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, empheq,braket,mathtools,stmaryrd,graphicx,subfigure,latexsym}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{csquotes}



\usepackage{bookmark}                      % segnalibri

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{bm} % per formule matematiche in grassetto


\usepackage{esint} %per integrale barrato


\usepackage[style=numeric,defernumbers]{biblatex}

%\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,useprefix,hyperref,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

And the structure of my main.tex file.

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Chapter One}

\input{Chapters/Introduction}

\chapter{Chapter Two}

\input{Chapters/Ex_and_uniq}

\backmatter

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to compile before using pdflatex, then using bibtex. What I get while compiling with bibtex is the following error message.

[image]

Any help?
I'm using TeXworks on a Mac. (Don't know if it's meaningful.)

Comment: You need to compile with Biber and not BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) as well as [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: Already seen that post. I can't find Biber on my computer to add it in the preferences of TeXworks

Comment: Please include your preamble and other code as well as error mesages as copyable plain text instead of as a picture. That makes it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In a modern TeX live installation Biber should be installed by default. Try if you can find it with `tlmgr`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Can you run Biber manually from the command line with `biber --version`? If your MacTeX is recent (which I believe it is, after all it identifies itself as TeX live 2015), you should find Biber in `/Library/TeX/texbin` I think (can't check, I'm not a Mac user).

Comment: Any news here? Did you get the compilation off the ground?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can you run Biber manually from the command line with biber --version? "?

Comment: However, I cannot find Biber in /Library/TeX....

Comment: Okay. Everything works. The problem was that when I was configuring TeXworks to use Biber I was not unticking "View PDF after running"